# How do I filter out for last rank only?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataset where for each unique `OrderID`, the status for a product changes overtime and the time for each of these changes is recorded.

I have grouped all the records by `OrderID` and ranked them. I now only want records that were the last rank for each `OrderID`.

```
Grouped = sortedOrdersAll.sort_values(['ordid','DateTime'],ascending=True).groupby(['ordid','DateTime']) 

Grouped.first()
```

[image: Ranked and grouped]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using a groupby I think you could do this

```
df.sort_values('DateTime').drop_duplicates(subset=['ordid'], keep='last')
```